# Wordpress Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

There is a plugin we are interested in, but our requirements need an additional feature.  The plugin author mentioned including this feature at an estimated cost of dollars.  This is fine, and not that I really care, but if we are going to pay for the development of this functionality, does the author have any right to sell copies of this?

Comment: Although I'm not a lawyer, but there is a strong possibility that he can't. Depending on the license, you only get to install it on one or several machines. modifications are fine, but you can't resell the product unless it can't be distinguished from the original product, and also allowed by the developer to be used in premium third party product.

Comment: Hello Jack, thank you for your reply, but I am considered with him taking the code we paid for and selling it as an upgrade to his already existing product.